# Tips on making responsive website fit for mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm currently trying to use CSS media queries to optimise my website for mobile view, and am using Google Chrome with an extension to resize the viewport on my desktop to adjust my content for mobile.

The problem I'm having is when i'm designing and changing on my laptop at the mobile phone resolution, everything works fine (see first picture) but when I actually load the website on my mobile, I'm not getting the same view as what I'm getting from the laptop (see second picture).

I've used

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

to set my width for mobile[image: Responsive view from laptop]

[image: View I'm actually getting from mobile]

I know the font is different because it's a third party i've installed onto my laptop so thats not the problem.

Just wondering if theres any easier way of actually creating responsive views for mobile such as using applications like Phonegap or if anyone can give me tips on how to properly create responsive content for mobile.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: 
The second picture is larger because it was as a screenshot from my mobile phone, the screen sizes aren't different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I suggest watching the New Boston's Responsive Web Design Playlist:

He will teach you the important basic concept of a responsive design using percentage and also creating your own custom menu or button in a responsive mobile version(that makes it almost like a mobile app in a browser).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWgl3xXVlHI&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBaTsb1nse1UU48d_q7glGT

Comment: Welcome. I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using bootstrap. It is a mobile first front-end framework for faster and easier web development
http://getbootstrap.com

Answer (score 0):

@John Appleseed
use the Inspector 
 "Toggle device mode"  or   "Ctrl + Shift + M" 
time you try your web site

and not just resize the page

I don't know your CSS but have a look at this

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp